# ddmmyyyy to sql datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert a `nvarchar` value to `datetime` in T-SQL. The value is in `ddmmyyyy` format, e.g. `23072009`

I need to convert to `datetime` in T-SQL.

I tried

```
select convert(datetime, '23072009', 103)
```

But it is throwing error.

> "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
> resulted in an out-of-range value."

Any idea

Thanks

Comment: What does the error look like?  Why are you giving `convert` an int instead of a string?

Comment: Please provide all the code and what is the error?

Comment: I'd advise you find a way to avoid treating `datetime`s as strings in the database in the first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rebuild your format to `yyyymmdd`.

```
declare @D varchar(8)
set @D = '23072009'

select cast(right(@D, 4)+substring(@D, 3, 2)+left(@D, 2) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 6):

The style 103 will accept strings with dd/mm/yyyy format. So your code should be

```
declare @date varchar(8)
set @date='23072009'
select convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(@date,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/')  , 103)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCustomDate] (@customDateString NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(@customDateString, 4) + RIGHT(LEFT(@customDateString, 4), 2) + LEFT(@customDateString, 2))

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Change VARCHAR (dd-mm-yyyy) to date (yyyy-mm-dd) in SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @VarDate VARCHAR(10)
SET @VarDate  = '22-02-1994'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE, @VarDate, 103), 102))
```

Comment: Please explain how this works, how it is supposed to solve the problem and how it differs from the existing and similar answer. Consider explaining the advantage of using this code compared to the others solutions. "just another way to do the same" is not really a reason to provide another answer to an eight year old question. But if you can point out an advantage in an explanation it might attract upvote.

Answer (score -2):

You need to cast a string and not a int. Put some quotes:

```
convert(datetime, '23072009', 103)
```

**And 103 gets the string like 'dd/mm/yyyy' and not 'ddmmyyyy'.**

Comment: That doesn't work - still getting: `Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

Comment: @marc_s yep I've seen your answer as well :) Just added the other part.