# SQL Server 2012 - varchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running views against a table that has dates stored as `varchar(8)` as DDMMYYYY, can someone please tell me how do I convert them to `date` format?

Thanks

Comment: Add the rdbms tag please

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ddmmyyyy to sql datetime in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034978/ddmmyyyy-to-sql-datetime-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(right(col, 4) + 0, substring(col, 3, 2) + 0, left(col, 2) + 0)
```

I just added the `+ 0`, because I'm not 100% sure if SQL Server will convert the arguments to integers.

Of course, you can also do it the "old" way as well:

```
select convert(date, right(col, 4) + substring(col, 3, 2) + left(col, 2))
```

SQL Server recognized the format YYYYMMDD as a valid date.

Comment: When i run this it converts value to dates allright. But how do I use this in the view to update table column contaning varchar dates ? ...sorry I am beginner in terms of sql.

Comment: @sqlsyntex1 . . . You should ask another question and be very explicit that you want to convert the existing column to a date column.  This question is likely to be closed soon anyway.